# Display pdf in phonegap App

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How can I display online PDF in `My Phonegap` App.

I am trying `iframe` but PDF is not display any other solution?

I want to display PDF from URL in my App not display in default PDF viewer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess you need to have a look at cordova InApp Broswer plugin - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Comment: but I want to display in my App page between header and footer . How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Google PDF viewer. It embeddeds a PDF given its URL in an online viewer. Then, you just have to use the resulting URL in the iframe `src`. Change the `url` query param with the URL of your PDF:

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf&embedded=true
```

Comment: Yes I have also tried this one but in old version samsung devices it's not working properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [A Document Viewer cordova/phonegap plugin for iOS and Android](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer)
 plugin for showing pdf within you application.

Comment: This plugin only for local file. I want to use for live URL of PDF

Answer (score -1):

Don't use iFrames on mobile, especially Cordova apps. My suggestion would be to use the [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) Plugin `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://linktopdf.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');` (will open the native safari viewer for iOS).

Getting this to work on Android is a bit more complicated. You can use the same approach above but swap `_blank` with `_system`. This downloads the PDF to the device through the default browser. The second, more involved approach for Android is to download the pdf file to the filesystem through a [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) in the app, and then [open](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) it through the default pdf reader.

Comment: but I want to display in my App page between header and footer . How can I do? InAppBrowser will open in different screen. But I want to open in same screen below header of my App.

Comment: That's simply not possible in an hybrid App on Android.