# pdf file (ByteArray) is not opening in cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, pdf

I am new to Cordova and recently started working on Cordova project, as part of my project requirement I need to open pdf byte array stream (pdf file)in android and iOS mobile phones.
I have added following line to open the pdf file in inappbrowser.

```
window.open( "data:application/pdf;base64," + pdfByteArray, "_blank");
```

When I install apk file and click on open pdf file link in android mobile it is not opening popup window and not getting any response from Cordova

but when I replace above line with below line the application is opening  Apache.org in new window.
     window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank');

I am using Cordova 6.0.0 and installed InAppBrowser Plug-in (1.2.0)

Any help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in using the InAppBowser. For Android however, InAppBrowser won't work. Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353023/display-pdf-in-phonegap-app/36388649#36388649).